# ¿Cómo estilizar botones con CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo una maqueta de una página web con HTML5 y CSS3. Sin frameworks ni nada por el estilo. Solamente lo que ofrecen los lenguajes.

¿Cómo podría replicar los botones de la siguiente captura?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con el siguiente código pero queda bastante mal:

```
<!-- HTML -->
    <a href="a" class="boton">Home</a>
    <a href="b" class="boton">Projects</a>
    <a href="d" class="boton">Downloads</a>
    <a href="e" class="boton">About</a>
    <a href="f" class="boton">Contact</a>

/* CSS */
    .boton{
      background-color: #EDEDED;
      border: 2px;
      border-color: #D5D5D5;
      color: #000000;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Edit 1: así quedan los botones con mi código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://bootswatch.com/slate/ puedes copiar los css de este template de bootstrap, alli hay unos botones muy similares a los que quieres

Comment: Dice que no quiere usar ningun framework y la pagina que linkeaste es puro bootstrap...

Answer (score 2):

Puedes lograrlo encerrando los enlaces en una lista desordenada `ul>li` y con `flexbox` css, de esta forma evitas los espacios en blanco entre enlaces, el resto es dar estilos a los botones.

```css
.btnlist {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.boton {
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 16px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: linear-gradient(#f2f2f2, #d8d8d8);
    border-left: 1px solid #f6f6f6;
    border-right: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
    color: #88787a;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.boton:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background: #ddd;
}
.btnlist li:first-child .boton {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
.btnlist li:last-child .boton {
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="btnlist">
    <li><a class="boton" href="a">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="boton" href="b">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a class="boton" href="c">Downloads</a></li>
    <li><a class="boton" href="d">About</a></li>
    <li><a class="boton" href="e">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

No se si quieres el mas oscuro en el `hover` o el `active`, lo coloqué en el hover.

Answer (score 1):

- Para el tema del módulo [*Flexbox*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox) recomiendo revises el enlace provisto a mayor profundidad
- A cada botón del menú le aplicamos estilos tales como:

  - `border` para la línea que rodea a cada botón
  - `color` para el color de la letra
  - `padding` para lograr un espacio entre el texto y el bóton que lo contiene
  - `text-decoration` para quitar el tema de subrayado
- Para seleccionar al primer y último elemento del menú nos apoyamos de las seudoclases [`first-child` y `last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

  - Lo anterior nos permitirá poder aplicar border redondeados mediante [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) solamente a esos elementos
  - Mediante `first-child` también aplicaremos el efecto de sombra al primer elemento mediante [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Código:

```html
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Arial; 
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      .contenedor {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .contenedor-menu {
        display: flex;
      }
      .contenedor-menu__boton {
        color: #777777;
        background-color: #E8E8E8;
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 60px;
      }
      .contenedor-menu__boton:first-child {
        background-color: #DDDDDD;
        border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
        box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 10px 1px  rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
      }
      .contenedor-menu__boton:last-child {
        border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0; 
      }
    </style>
    
    <nav class="contenedor">
      <ul class="contenedor-menu">
        <a href="a" class="contenedor-menu__boton">Home</a>
        <a href="b" class="contenedor-menu__boton">Projects</a>
        <a href="d" class="contenedor-menu__boton">Downloads</a>
        <a href="e" class="contenedor-menu__boton">About</a>
        <a href="f" class="contenedor-menu__boton">Contact</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Y la salida sería así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ya necesitas aplicar el estilo que puse fijo al primer botón cuando el cursor pase encima de cada botón, entonces apoyate de la [pseudoclase `:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) ya eso te lo dejo a ti :)